# BDD Proper Given Setup

Tags: php, bdd, behat

Current company decided to switch over to BDD using selenium, PHP, and Behat and from my understanding of the gherkin language of using Given, it's the 'pre-condition' or context of the scenario, but I'm confused on the implementation if it's beyond a simple Given: I'm on the login page.

So if I have a feature file like:

```
Feature: Sign up for an account

Scenario: Register using a temporary email address

Given I register a temporary email address at https://getnada.com/

And I register an account

And I click the link in my email to confirm new account

When I complete the registration process by setting a password

Then I should be on the User Profile page
```

What I get confused about is that in some instances with Given, you can initiate the webbrowser in that step, and other examples I've seen, people have explicit data underneath the given statement.

I'm not sure if I should automate the given steps so if I run the same script, it could grab a new email address

or

I should have just completed the Given steps and pass the email address and registration information explicitly, since the information is already assumed given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of the scenario contains things which happened before the scenario starts. An easy way to get this right is to put them into the past or continous present tense. So these are all contexts:

```
Fred bought a microwave for £100
I have an account with StackOverflow
Luke has the winning lottery ticket
I saved my document as "LostDog.docx"
```

Givens should really be independent of each other; it shouldn't matter what order they happen in. (Feel free to compromise this rule for readability.)

In your scenario, two of the Givens lead to the next Given:

```
Given I register a temporary email address at https://getnada.com/
And I register an account
And I click the link in my email to confirm new account
```

So it's OK to summarize it with one Given that represents the end-state of that.

```
Given I've clicked to confirm a new account with a getnada.com email address
```

It looks from the scenario as if you might be interested in exercising all the behaviour associated with clicking the link and completing the registration. If that's the case, I'd rephrase with something like:

```
Given I've requested a new account with a getnada.com email address
When I finish the registration by setting a password...
```

In either case, those larger steps can contain the smaller steps within them.

Note that in the case of the Givens, it *shouldn't matter how you got there*. Maybe you actually sent yourself an email. Maybe you just used the API. Maybe you just put the relevant data directly into the database (careful, that can be a bit brittle). You're not exercising the behaviour of the system in this case.

If you do want to exercise any behaviour, it goes in the When rather than the Given.

If you have a conversation with someone who understands the problem you're trying to solve, and ask them for an example of how it should work, they'll usually summarize these fairly effectively for you. That's another reason the conversations are a very important part of BDD.

See also the Page Object pattern, which will help to keep the steps maintainable when you do this.

Comment: Thank you so much that explanation helped out a lot.

Comment: Nice and straightforward explanation by @lunivore, I would also like to add that you should try to avoid being too verbose regarding the Given-context, since it tends to "steal away" the attention when reading the scenario. E.g. instead of putting the effort describing the interaction with a user being able to click a link inside an email ...you could simply state `Given I have confirmed to create a new account` [..]. Also, I've noticed you're missing something quite important that's related to the feature it self - the narrative of the user story e.g.`As a new user In order to..[..]`

Comment: ..since `Scenarios` are (usually) a type of acceptance criteria. Might be useful to read https://dannorth.net/whats-in-a-story/ and http://behat.org/en/latest/quick_start.html#example

Comment: @IdrizŠunja Scenarios *illustrate* acceptance criteria. https://lizkeogh.com/2011/06/20/acceptance-criteria-vs-scenarios/ The difference is specific (getnada.com, £100) versus generic (an email site, a price). It's a really common mix-up that trips up a lot of newcomers so worth clarifying. Commonly people put the actual rules / acceptance criteria in the blurb at the top of the feature file. +2 for the links though, particularly Dan's.

Answer (score 0):

Does not matter, they are just keywords to help you see better the sections of a scenario and to help you to make a sense of the scenario.

> **Given** some initial context
>   **When** I do something
>   **Then** result

In given you can do the setup for the scenarios or just open a page.

Examples:

Given I have a new account

Given I have an invalid email like test@mail

Given I am on the homepage

> You need to remember the focus of the scenario

```
Given I am on register page
When I fill register form with valid info
And I submit the register form
Then I should be on the User Profile page
```

```
Given I have a new account
When I login with the new account
Then I should be on the User Profile page
```

The first scenario is for register and the focus is on filling the register form and submit, you can also use some data if you need too in the fill step.

The second scenario is for login, you focus on login and the Given contains the registration under a single step.

> If something seems odd or to hard then you are doing something wrong
>   If the scenario is too complex then you are missing some points
>   The scenario should be easy to read and to understand without being lost in the details
>   Write is as natural as possible as you would do for a manual test
>   Finally, I recommend to read a book about BDD like BDD in action